# When is a JavaScript Property NOT an Identifier?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading this article: http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/.

Which makes the following statement:

> Just like when looking up properties, if the property you are defining
> is an identifier, you can use dot syntax instead of bracket syntax.
> For instance, you could say man.sex = "male" in the example above.

I looked up identifiers in JavaScript because I was a little confused on this statement and found this article: http://coderkeen.com/old/articles/identifiers-en.html.
It says:

> An identifier is regarded as a value which is unique in relation to
> all the other identifiers in a system.

and later:

> Javascript makes no exclusion and identifiers are used for:
>
> Variable names
> Function names
> Names of formal parameters of functions

As the title implies:

When would I end up with a property of a JavaScript object which wasn’t an identifier and could thus not be accessed using the `.` syntax? Or am I misreading something?

Comment: e.g. with `var obj = { 'foo-bar': 'something' };` where you could NOT use `obj.foo-bar`, but `obj['foo-bar']`

Comment: You can have `object['foo bar']` or `object['foo-bar']`

Comment: Array elements are also referred to as "properties" in the spec, but their names are numbers, not identifiers.

Comment: @BenM: it's the *property name*, it is *not* an identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I looked up identifiers in JavaScript because I was a little confused
>   on this statement and find [this](http://coderkeen.com/old/articles/identifiers-en.html):
>
> > An identifier is regarded as a value which is unique in relation to all the other
> >     identifiers in a system.

The dot syntax does refer to identifiers as a *syntax element*, as they are specified in [EcmaScript 5 §7.6](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6). It means they must not contain whitespaces or punctuation marks, for example.

While `"foo-bar x"` can be used as a property name of an object, you cannot access it via dot syntax `obj.foo-bar x` because it would be ambigous. You need to use bracket notation `obj["foo-bar x"]` instead.

Another common example are array indices. Technically they're just properties of the Array object as well, just as `.length` is. However, as integers are no identifiers (which must not begin with a digit) you cannot write `arr.0` but have to use `arr[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this.  Much appreciated.  I'm accepting your answer because of the clarifications.  Very helpful.

Comment: just a quick follow up, is obj["foo-barX"] with no spaces treated as an identifier?  IE It isn't the  way the property is assigned that matters, but rather the spaces (characteristics of the property name)?

Comment: Yes, only the `foobarX` would be the identifier string. But notice that identifier must not contain a minus sign :-) Check how [property syntax is defined](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1): either `<someExpression>.<IdentifierName>` or `<someExpression>[<anyExpression>]`

Answer (score 3):

```
var someobject = {};
someobject["I'm a turtle"] = true;
```

`I'm a turtle` is most definitely not an identifier!

Comment: Ok I can accept that's the case, could you explain why though?  It's not clear to me what "I'm a turtle" is in this case.

Comment: @NathanielWaggoner It is a property. But it can't be accessed via dot syntax because of the spacing and quote. IOW you can't do `someobject.I'm a turtle`